# Find a two-dimensional minimal sufficient statistic for $(\theta,j)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be a random sample from a distribution with discrete probability $f_{\theta,j}$, where $\theta \in (0,1)$, $j=1,2$, $f_{\theta,1}$ is the Poisson distribution with mean $\theta$, and $f_{\theta,2}$ is the binomial distribution with size $1$ and probability $\theta$. Find a two-dimensional minimal sufficient statistic for $(\theta,j)$.

**Approach:**

The joint distribution of $X$ is given as $$f_{\theta}(x) = \left[ \frac{e^{- \theta} \theta ^{\sum X_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i !} I_{\{j=1\}}. \theta^{\sum X_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum X_i} I_{\{j=2\}} \right]$$
which can be re-arranged as:
$$\left[ \frac{e^{-\theta}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i !} I_{\{j=1\}} (1-\theta)^n I_{\{j=2\}} \right]. \exp\{ \sum X_i \log \theta. I_{\{j=1\}} + \sum X_i \log \left( \frac{\theta}{1-\theta} \right) I_{\{j=2\}} $$.

Seems like $\sum X_i$ is minimal sufficient but turns out it is not sufficient for $(\theta,j)$.
Intuitively, we should have a two-dimensional statistic to minimal sufficient but I don't have a clue about how to find it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3521107/321264

Comment: I somehow feel that $\mathbf I_{[\max X_i >1]}$ might be useful

Comment: Actually I saw that $W=1_{{\{X=0\} \ \text{or} \ \{X=1 \}}}$ is jointly sufficient along with $\sum X_i$ but I am not sure how to prove that

Comment: I deleted my answer because there exists a solution by the author of the exercise in the free [exercise book, p. 64](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-28276-9).